# Behavior of overloaded operator new[] depends on destructor

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator

The following code snippet overloads `operator new[]` and prints out the `size` required and pointer addresses

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int _data;    //sizeof(MyClass) == 4

public:
    void* operator new[](size_t size)
    {
        cout << "MyClass::operator new[]" << endl;
        cout << "size = " << size << endl;
        void* p = malloc(size);
        cout << "p = " << p << endl;
        return p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass* a = new MyClass[100];
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
}
```

output

```
>>  MyClass::operator new[]
>>  size = 400
>>  p = 0x55e335a3f280
>>  a = 0x55e335a3f280
```

However, by explicitly adding/defining a destructor

```
class MyClass
{
...
public:
    ...
    ~MyClass() {}
};

int main()
{
    MyClass* a = new MyClass[100];
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
}
```

the result changed

```
>>  MyClass::operator new[]
>>  size = 408
>>  p = 0x564f30cd7280
>>  a = 0x564f30cd7288
```

meaning that expression `new[]` is requesting an extra 8 bytes of memory from `operator new[]`. The extra bytes of memory seems to be storing the size of the array, and can even be accessed!

```
cout << "info: " << *(reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(a) - 1) << endl;
```

result

```
>>  info: 100
```

My question is who and why is using this 8 bytes of information? Is this a part of the standard? If so, is there an explanation to why it is designed to behave this way?

Comment: Note that `new[]` expression is requesting extra 8 _bytes_ of memory, not _bits_.

Comment: Oops, I'll fix the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [unspecified](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#15.4) whether there is, and how much, overhead there is when calling any array `new`. This behaviour is well within the leniency afforded to the compiler. The extra space is typically used to indicate how many elements there are in the array.

On calling `delete[]`, the destructor of every element needs to be called; this can only be done if we know how many elements there are. In the case where the elements have trivial destructors, none of them needs to be called and therefore no space is required.

Note that although implementations typically delegate to `std::free` in `operator delete`, it isn't guaranteed and you should overload `operator delete` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should see similar behaviour if you instead of a destructor add a member with a non-trivial destructor, such as a `std::string`.

When you have a destructor, the runtime needs to know how many elements there are so it can destroy them before destroying the array.

The standard does not specify how any of this should be implemented, but storing metadata just before the actual data is simple, convenient, and efficient.